# Android Studio: How to create particular Alert Dialog based on where the user clicks

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio programming. My program has a recyclerview with 3 Textviews, and one image. I would like an alert dialog to appear based on where the user clicks on the screen, for instance if the user clicks on the image the dialog says, "You clicked on image". If the user clicks on the text, it would say "You clicked on the text".
My onclick listener is as follows:  `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int index = getAdapterPosition();
        if (playerNames.equals(index)) {
            showDialogPlayerNames();
        }
        if (numberPlayers.equals(index)){
            showDialogPlayerNumber();
        }
        if (ScorePlayers.equals(index)){
            showDialogPlayerScore();
        }
        if (picturePlayers.equals(index)) {
            showDialogPlayerImage();
        }
    }
    }
```

Here is my alert dialog code:

```
void showDialogPlayerNames() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Click Information");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_info_24);
    alertDialog.setMessage("You clicked Player Name");
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.create().show();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameters in your methods

```
showDialogPlayerNames("Something text here");


void showDialogPlayerNames(String myText) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(myText);
}
```

Comment: My issue lies within my if statement, the dialog worked without the if statement. How can I make the listener show a different alert dialog based on where the user clicks?